# Running 32-bit Programs in CentOS 7 Container on OpenWrt: Troubleshooting Steamcmd Issue

Tags: centos, x86-64, centos7, steam, openwrt

I'm running a CentOS 7 container inside a Docker on OpenWrt with the following kernel version: Linux iStoreOS 5.10.176 #0 SMP Tue Jul 25 05:14:16 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux. However, no matter what I try, I can't run the 32-bit version of steamcmd within the CentOS 7 container. It gives the following error:
./steamcmd.sh: line 37: /home/steamcmd/linux32/steamcmd: cannot execute binary file.
What could be the issue? Why can't a 64-bit CentOS run a 32-bit program? I've already installed the required dependencies for running 32-bit programs: glibc.i686, libstdc++.i686, libcurl4-gnutls-dev.i686, and libcurl.i686.

Expected that the steamcmd program would execute successfully without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by set these two flags [CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION=y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4SwY.png),
[CONFIG_X86_X32=y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkb7X.png) in kernel config and recompile the openwrt firmware.

Flags:

```
CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION=y
CONFIG_X86_X32=y
```

After that you also need to install some libs in your CentOS container.

This works fine for me.
[Steamcmd works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSeDn.png)

Comment: `CONFIG_X86_X32` is an ILP32 ABI for 64-bit mode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).  It's entirely unrelated to i386 / i686 compatibility.  Does OpenWRT actually use 64-bit x32 binaries as well as i386 binaries?  If not, you don't need that kernel support.